# Is there a version of Pokemon in which you could get the leftover starter?

Tags: pokemon-series

So with each of the Pokemon games, you generally start with three choices of Pokemon - a Fire, Grass, or Water type. You chose that, and your rival usually chooses the most effective pokemon when compared to your choice, eg: Water against Fire.

I recall that there was a point in a version of Pokemon where you could go back and take the third Pokemon, whichever one got left over. **Am I dreaming there, or can you go and get that third Pokemon in a game? If so, which version?**

Comment: This seems so familiar. I swear I could even remember a line like "it has become lonely, so why dont you take care of it"

Answer (score 16, accepted):

There is no game where you can claim the leftover Pokemon after choosing your starter.

In some games (such as Black and White), both unchosen Pokemon are given to NPCs. In others (like Red and Blue), the unused Pokemon sits neglected on a table all game long. There is no way for the player to get this Pokemon in any version.

In Pokemon Yellow, it is possible to get all three first-generation starters, although you don't start with any of them, so that still doesn't meet the criteria you set forth.

In some games, it is possible to get starters from past generations by completing certain requirements after beating the elite four. For example, in HeartGold and SoulSilver, you can get a 3rd-generation starter in the Silph Co. building, but you can never pick up the "missing" 2nd-generation starter that wasn't picked early on in the game.

Comment: Yellow seems familiar... how did you get them all in that game?

Comment: @SimonSheehan In Yellow your "starter" was Pikachu, and you got Bulbasaur, Charmander, and Squirtle in Cerulean City, Route 24, and Vermillion City respectively.

Comment: I can't recall if you can aquire eevee in yellow or not.  That might be the game in question

Answer (score 4):

You might be thinking of a trading cheat used in Red and Blue to get all the starters with only two games and not having to do much work.

Once you start a game you could get your starter, get to the point where you could use pokeballs and the pokemon trading center. There you could trade with another person who wanted the starter pokemon for something like a rattata or pidgey. Then you would reset the game, and start the process over again to get a different or more starters. Then when you are done, trade the pokemon back to your game to get 'ALL' the starters.

I remember this because all of my friends had gotten to the fourth gym, but didn't want to trade their starters away or reset their game. Since I just started, my game was the 'reset' game everyone could use to get starters because I hadn't gotten too far.

Answer (score -1):

In the original silver and gold you could use the cloning glitch with the starters and get all three

Comment: I don't think the asker was looking for a way to glitch or cheat multiple starter Pokémon into their party.

Answer (score -2):

In Pokemon XY after defeating the Elite Four, you'll go back to your house and you'll meet Shauna. she will ask to trade, and she will trade you one of the starter Pokemon:

- *Froakie*, if your starter was *Chespin*.
- *Chespin* if you chose *Fennekin*.
- *Fennekin* if you chose *Froakie*.

PS: You can trade ANY Pokemon from your PC or party, so I suggest you trade Shauna a common Pokemon, like a Pidgey.

Comment: While true, it isn't the 'leftover' starter from the beginning of the game, as all starters are technically in use by your rivals/friends.

Answer (score -4):

Save the game, then pick one, and then capture any one Pokemon in the grass. Give your starter a Pokeball as a Held Item. Store your starter, let's call it PK1, in box 1 on PC. You should now only have one useless Pokemon in your team.

This is the magic part here:

You switch to box 2, but after it prompts you to save, you turn off the game/reset at a magic moment. The letter F and P, between the word (turn) ofF* + *The (power). You turn it on and if you timed it well, you should be standing before the three Pokémon again.

Pick the next starter, PK2. Go to PC and pull out PK1 and take the Pokeball off it again. Catch another useless Pokémon. Place PK1 & PK2 in box 1. Again you only have a useless Pokémon in your party.

Switch to box 2 while hitting the magic moment as you did prior, and you will again be in front of the trio. Pick last Pokémon, PK3. Go to PC and pull out PK1 & PK2.

You should now have each starter Pokemon, PK 1, 2 & 3. Save the game normally.

Comment: Hi Joe, which Pokemon game are you talking about explicitly?